# Show file names in listbox for selected directory in treeview

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, treeview

I have a button "Choose folder". When i choose folder, it shows all the directories and sub-directories in treeview. Everything is working fine.
What i need now is - when i click in the treeview on some directory in shows all files that is in that directory in the listbox.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath);
        if (directoryInfo.Exists)
        {
            VeidotKoku(directoryInfo, treeView1.Nodes);
        }
    }
}

private void VeidotKoku(DirectoryInfo directoryInfo, TreeNodeCollection Pievienot)
{
    TreeNode tagadejaNode = Pievienot.Add(directoryInfo.Name);

    foreach (DirectoryInfo subdir in directoryInfo.GetDirectories())
    {
        VeidotKoku(subdir, tagadejaNode.Nodes);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileLocationPath);

Will get the extensionless path.

Else, if you just want to get the value you can split the path and get the last element.

```
foreach(string filePath in filePaths)
{
    string[] brokenPath = filePath.Split('/');
    listBox.Add(brokenPath.Last());
}
```

Top of my head.